# How to walk out of a place that has an ark?

Tags: synagogue, ark-aron-kodesh

See my answer to this [M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87301/5275).

My follow up question - Are the rules applicable to only a "formal" *bet Knesset*, i.e. a building established as such? Or is it dependent on the presence of an ark? For example, if one is in a shiva home and there is an ark present there for the week, would one have to walk out sideways?

Comment: Are the rules applicable to an _aron kodesh_, or is it for the _sifrei Torah_ inside?

Comment: @ezra That's an interesting nuance. I don't think an empty aron has any *kedusha* when it is empty. Thus, I don't believe that one would fall on the face for tachanun if he were in a shul that had an empty aron. The problem, of course, is that most of the time they are closed and covered, so you may not know.